# PayPal rest api not saving 'live'

Tags: rest, api, paypal, sandbox

I have had an app developed in it processed orders in 'sandbox' mode. No I've tried a live payment it just keeps spinning on the app.

I went to the rest api on the PayPal Developer site, but when I click from 'sandbox to live' and click save it reverts back to sandbox.

The developer of the app is not being very helpful and PayPal is difficult to get help from.... so I have found this place ;-)

Hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try again in different web browsers by clearing cookies and cache. If you are still persisting the same issue, kindly file an MTS ticket for PayPal at: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ , with screenshots and steps for reproducing ths issue. Then you will get help from the PayPal MTS team.